# How do I get 2 Dell monitors to work with my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

OSX doesn't support MST daisy chaining monitors. I've got 2 brand new monitors and a decent mac and Apple wont let me use it due to software limitations.

Is there any product I can buy (Amazon preferably) that will let me use my two monitors (not screen mirroring) as I want to? I can plug both displays into the mac but then I can't charge the mac at the same time or close the lid without it going off. Dell U2518D are the displays.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more than one monitor, you need to use two different connections, in your case Thunderbolt (Displayport) and some other connection, like HDMI or a dedicated Displayport connection. To do this you need a Thunderbolt 3 dock solution that supports this ability. There are many, such as [Elgato](https://www.elgato.com/en/dock/thunderbolt-3), [Belkin](https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U093/) or [CalDigit](http://www.caldigit.com/thunderbolt-3-dock/thunderbolt-station-3-plus/).

A recent (December 2018) [Wirecutter](https://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-thunderbolt-dock/) review is a good place to start.

Comment: It sucks that because Apple can't be bothered adding MST daisychain support I have to spend an extra £200/$300 on something to make my monitors work. OSX is the only thing keeping me with Apple products right now, which is a shame. Thanks for the recommendations though, I appreciate it.

Comment: FWIW, I have a CalDigit, and love the convenience of all the ports. I plug in my Thunderbolt cable, and I get external harddrives, a monitor, Ethernet, USB sound all connected. Its even hidden under my desk  so no dongletown for me...so there are benefits to that $300 (just a happy customer, not paid endorsement)